How can i make the HoloLens adjust the scene from unity according to the eye level of the person wearing it the HoloLens?
I want to change the scene when I enter play mode to the eye-level of the person wearing it since every time I open a scene from Unity, it either shows far away from me or at the location where I launched the HoloLens Remoting Player. I attempted to add eye-gaze to the features, but it was unsuccessful. I don't want to have to restart the project or move in order to interact with the virtual items.

Try using Solver+Orbital to keep scene objects at eye level.


Apart from using solvers, you could also do the following. Assuming sceneContent contains your mixed reality scene content and distanceOffset is the desired/specified distance between scene content and user head:
// Get user head (main camera)
Transform userHead = Camera.main.transform;

// Parent scene content to main camera/user head
sceneContent.transform.SetParent(userHead, false);

// Put scene content in front of user (using local coords)
sceneContent.transform.SetLocalPositionAndRotation(Vector3.forward, Quaternion.identity);

// Put scene content on same height as user head (using world coords)
Vector3 modifiedPos = sceneContent.transform.position;
sceneContent.transform.SetParent(userHead, false);
modifiedPos.y = userHead.position.y;
sceneContent.transform.position = modifiedPos;

// Place scene content at given distance from user
sceneContent.transform.localPosition = sceneContent.transform.localPosition.normalized * distanceOffset;

// Unparent scene content
sceneContent.transform.SetParent(null);

// Make scene content face user
sceneContent.transform.LookAt(userHead);

// Rotate scene content about y-axis for 180° if necessary
// sceneContent.transform.Rotate(Vector3.up, 180);

// Enable scene content
sceneContent.SetActive(true);

